# Catching signal SIGINT still kills the program

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm writing my own mini-bash and I wanted to disable default SIGINT behaviour (only "exit" should terminate bash) but SIGINT may kill running children (for example running "sleep 60 | sleep 30").

For catching SIGINT I'm using `signal(SIGINT, catchSignal);` function. The problem is that sending ^C inside my minibash still kills it =(

According to GNU: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html

**EDIT:** Perhaps it's worth to mention that it works as intended on Mac, not on Linux!

`A signal handler is just a function that you compile together with the rest of the program. Instead of directly invoking the function, you use signal or sigaction to tell the operating system to call it when a signal arrives.`

So I understand that when I push ^C, my catchSignal() is going to be executed and NOTHING BUT THIS. Right?

If yes then why my minibash terminates, this is my catchSignal(). It indeed does have `kill()` but only for running children.

**Sample execution**

```
[22:33:31][user][~/edu/sysprog/lab4]$ ./minibash 
mbash% ^CCatched Sigint
Inside Sigint
No children
```

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "sighant.h"

// Global variable
extern pidList children;

void catchSignal(int recvSign)
{
    printf("Catched Sigint\n");
    if(recvSign == SIGINT)
    {
        printf("Inside Sigint\n");
        if(children.count < 1)
        {
            printf("No children\n");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < children.count; i++)
        {
            if(children.child[i] >= 0)
            {
                printf("KILLIN\n\n");
                kill(children.child[i], SIGKILL);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] Could not execute Signal! (reason uknown)");
    }
}
```

**CODE2**

```
int main(void)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "mbash%% ");
    fflush(stderr);

    signal(SIGINT, catchSignal);

    .......
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of the main? Everything seems fine, maybe your mbash ends, because it has nothing left to do? You can also check, if signal() worked properly, here is a good example: [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/) Or try catching some other signal as well (like USR1), send it from other console and see what happens.

Comment: How are you making your children? pthreads or just forking? edit: probably not pthreads if you're killing them with `kill`. Forking and signal handling is not trivial.

Comment: The exit code of your mini shell should tell if it was terminated by a signal, and if so, by which signal.

Comment: Yeah @DarthHunterix . Right after it I have while(fgets(..., stdin) != NULL). For some reason this signal(); catch sends NULL to stdin and therefore my program simply terminates execution. Not sure why it happens. Perhaps I'll have to hack this by pushing "0" to stdin or something.

Comment: Better add a condition like "((fgets(..., stdin) != NULL) || interrupted)). If interrupt is detected you just ignore NULL and get back to normal processing. Anyway, I'm kinda new around so don't mind me asking this: does my comment counts an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest adding a `siginterrupt(SIGINT, 0);` after establishing the signal handler, and read up about interrupted system primitives vs. `signal(3)`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I am having this issue as well.